# Selenium untrusted SSL certificates don't work

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, ssl

This is very common problem on web, I was trying a lot of solutions, but nothing works. I want to run test with standard selenium firefox browser.

What I've already done:

- **trustAllSSLCertificates** attribute while running selenium server,
- generate firefox profile on desktop and send it to server, than I import it into selenium server by attribute
  **firefoxProfileTemplate** doesn't work at all
- add below code to test configuration

  ```
  <var name="testing.selenium.capabilities" value='{"acceptSslCerts" :true, "trustAllSSLCertificates" : true,"webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs":true, "setAcceptUntrustedCertificates":true,"acceptUntrustedCertificates":true}'/>
  ```

I use latest version of selenium server (2.42.2), I was trying with older one (2.39) nothing happen :( It this moment I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried going onto the profile on the server directly, and accepting the certificates? And are you 100% sure that it's using the right profile?

Comment: Yes I accept certificates manually. Than I send whole profile directory to server and run it with proper path.

Comment: It might be work looking at: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/951920